# What's the natural way to express raising to the power of 2 (e.g.5²) and higher exponents (5³ and , 5⁴)?

Tags: mathematics, reading-aloud

What's the way/s that native English speakers say this number (5<sup>2</sup>)  in words?

Is there a shorter way than "Five to the power of 2"?

For example:

> If you take 5<sup>2</sup> (in words?) and divide it into 5 is equal to 5.

Comment: I believe it is (or used to be) common in American English to say e.g. "five square", the "squared" usage being mainly used in the British English zone.

Comment: We say "five squared" and not "five square" to talk about exponention in American English. We would say "five square feet" when talking about a unit of area.

Comment: "5^2" is not a "power of 2".

Comment: BTW, you can properly typeset powers in Markdown by using HTML superscripts: `5<sup>4</sup>`. Or use Unicode superscript characters: 5², 5³, 5⁴...

Comment: By the way, as someone with a mathematical background, I would take "5^2, divided into 5" as being 5 / 25 = 0.2.  You need to say either "divide it by X" or "divide it into X pieces" to clarify which number is the dividend and which is the divisor.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki no, but it *is* "five raised to the power of two". "Five squared" or "five to the second" are both more common but not more correct.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

5<sup>2</sup> is "five squared".

5<sup>3</sup> is "five cubed".

5<sup>4</sup> is "five to the power of four", "five to the power four", "five to the fourth power", "five to the fourth", or "five to the four".

From the comments, it seems some English speakers are unfamiliar with the shorter *"to the four"* way of saying things, but the following sources (among others) attest to it:

- *We can call this “x raised to the power of n,” “x to the power of n,” or simply “x to the n.”* (see [here](https://mathinsight.org/exponentiation_basic_rules))
- *5<sup>4</sup> typically reads as “five to the four” or “five to the fourth”.* (see [here](https://exponentiations.com/))
- *10<sup>4</sup> could be called "10 to the fourth power", "10 to the power 4" or "10 to the 4"* (see [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/index-notation-powers.html))

Comment: Is saying "5 to the power of 2" (instead of "5 squared") considered odd?

Comment: No, not necessarily, although at school, kids learn about squares and cubes before they learn about exponents in general, so in non-mathematical circles, "5 squared" is more widely understood, whereas if you say "5 to the power of 2" then many people may look confused.

Comment: If you are calculating the area a a 5x5 carpet then 5 squared is normal. Otherwise it doesn't matter much. It's easier to speak and write as 5 squared. However if you are comparing the properties of different powers x to the power n is perfectly acceptable.  Cross-posted with rjpond's comment.

Comment: FWIW I'm a mathematician and BrE speaker and "to the power *of* n" sounds odd (although not incorrect) to me; I almost never hear anybody include the "of".

Comment: I wonder if anyone has ever seriously used "five tesseracted"

Comment: @Chronocidal The answer is probably no.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: Are you sure?  I’m also a mathematician and BrE speaker, and “5 to the power 4” without “of” sounds much less standard to me.  Normally (among STEM professionals/students) I’d just say “5 to the 4th” without “power”, but if including “power” (e.g. to be clearer to a layperson) then I would always say “…power of 4”, and my intuition is that that’s more common than “power” without “of”.

Comment: @Chronocidal You can find a whole discussion thread on this topic here: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/uczzx/squared_cubed_tesseracted/

Comment: @Chronocidal “five hypercubed”

Comment: The fun part is that “squared” etymologically has a four in it.

Comment: I'm Canadian raised and a US resident for nearly 30 years (about half and half).  This is the correct answer, but I don't believe I've ever heard: *"five to the four"*.  The exception is the example: *“x to the n.”*; I'd say that if I was describing something symbolically (as an algebraic statement).  But, you might also hear me say *"x to the nth"* sometimes.

Comment: In some dialects, "five power n" is used as well (for general "n" and for specific values of n).

Comment: @Flydog57 I wonder if it's a British thing, or a physicist thing, because "five to the four" seems very common to me, and I'm both

Answer (score 0):

"Power of n" indicates that n is the base. To indicate that it's the exponent, the phrasing is "nth power". So, for instance, 5^2 is the second power of 5, 5 raised to the second power, or 5 to the second. The second power is usually referred to as squared and the third power as cubed.

Comment: On its own, "power of 5" would mean 2 was the base, but the form the OP used was "**to the** power of 5", which is commonly used as an equivalent of "to the 5th power", at least here in the UK.

Comment: That first sentence looks wrong to me. In a context like ***Two to the power [of] three***, 2 is the "base" and 3 is the "exponent" (or "power"), as OP already knows. And so far as I'm concerned, it's not idiomatic *anywhere* to refer to ***5 to the second***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica "five to the second" is a common way to say 5^2, at least in the US.  Like page 131 of this book says: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Everything_Guide_to_Pre_Algebra/QS3sDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22five+to+the+second%22+%225+2%22&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover or page 59 of this one: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Teaching_English_Learners_and_Students_w/g723SIDM4z4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22five+to+the+second%22&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover

Comment: "power of two" means two is it base in the sentence "eight is **a** power of two" but it's not incorrect to say "eight is two to the power of three".

Comment: Well, that first sentence is correct, but that's not the phrase the question used. 128 is indeed a power of 2, but 5 _to the_ power of 2 is 25. In the first one, 2 is the base, in the second, it's the exponent. That's two different phrases, similar, but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

These are obscure, and probably not understood, but are real words:

zenzizenzic - 4th power

zenzic cube - 6th power

zenzizenzizenzic - 8th power.

(IIRC, Arabic in origin, through German to English.  Lit. "square of the square", "square of the cube", "square of the square of the square".)

Don't have my source with me.

Comment: I'm not sure an obsolete and obscure mathematical notation term falls under "a natural way to express 5²".